# need my list of facebook friends to show up in adobe flex application

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, adobe, flex4.5

In an application I have created (web) I need to list out my facebook friends within a canvas (or any container) along with their profile pictures.

I am using Flash Builder 4.5. I have also managed to set up AIR app (using the samples) so I am not sure if I am on the right track.

The requirement is :

When each user logs into the site his/her friends list should appear in the frame along with the friend's profile pictures.

Comment: I think you'll need to do that in your server-side scripts, perhaps? If you're using PHP, you'd need to do that in PHP. Then send the results to Flex. This is how I'd do it.

Comment: Would you happen to have some sample for it... ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Facebook's AS3 API](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/) to implement these features.

Comment: Ya Sean, I have them already...just wanted to know how to pull the information and drop it in a canvas.

Comment: There are docs for the API, are you saying you don't want to read them?